# Volume by washers

Tags: calculus

I'm having some problems getting the desired answer for one of my problems and I would like some direction. I was able to get the first part of this problem, so I'll omit that part.

I have the lines:

$y=2-x$ and $y=0$ and $x=0$

I need to revolve that about line the line $y=3$

I'm able to see that this is a washer, so I set up the integral as follows:

$\int_{-1}^{2} \pi * (R^2 - r^2)h = \int_{-1}^{2} \pi * ((3)^2 - (x+1)^2)dx$

The correct answer is $\frac{28\pi}{3}$ but evaluating my integral, I get $18\pi$, so clearly something is wrong.

Comment: There are two problems. First, $x=0$ is one of the lines bounding the region, so your limits should not extend below $x=0$. (Yours go to $x=-1$.) Second, at a particular $x$-value, say $x=a$, the outer radius of the washer at $x=a$ is $3$, but the inner radius of the washer is not $2-a$, because $2-a$ is the distance from the $x$-axis ($y=0$) to the graph of $y=2-x$, not (as it should be) the distance from the line $y=3$  to the graph of $y=2-x$. If you draw a picture of the region that’s revolved and draw in a sample rectangle that becomes a washer when revolved, you should see what to do.

Comment: @SteveKass in regards to the second issue, I entered the wrong equation for the smaller radius, it has been edited. I am working on fixing the limits now.

Comment: Fixed the limits and got the correct answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

(Answering my own question with @SteveKass help):

Limits of the definite integral should be 0 -> 2 (because the integral is with respect to x, not y as I had mistaken).

New integral should be:

$\int_{0}^{2} \pi * ((3)^2 - (x+1)^2)dx$

(The $(x+1)$ came from solving for the smaller radius, $3 - (2-x)$)

Solving the integral: $\pi*(\frac{-8}{3} - 4 + 16) = \frac{28\pi}{3}$